# Installing odbc package

Tags: r, odbc

I am trying to use the new RStudio Connection Pane to set up an ODBC connection. When I try to do this I get the error message:

> Required package versions could not be found: odbc 1.1.1 is required but 1.0.1 is available

I have tried installing the latest odbc package by running:

```
devtools::install_github("r-dbi/odbc")
```

It runs for quite some time but not until the end. The last part of the log is:

> Warning in file.copy(files, dest, overwrite = TRUE) :   problem
>   copying .\odbc.dll to
>   C:\Users\Daniel.Thuresson\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\odbc\libs\x64\odbc.dll:
>   Permission denied
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** tests
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]) :    there is no package called 'bit'
>
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'odbc'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/Daniel.Thuresson/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/odbc'
>   * restoring previous 'C:/Users/Daniel.Thuresson/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/odbc'
>
> Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date
>   = TRUE) :   problem copying C:\Users\Daniel.Thuresson\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\00LOCK-r-dbi-odbc-b3d159a\odbc\libs\x64\odbc.dll
>   to
>   C:\Users\Daniel.Thuresson\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\odbc\libs\x64\odbc.dll:
>   Permission denied
>
> Error: Command failed (1)
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In value[3L] : object 'odbcListDrivers' not found
>
> 2: In value[3L] : object 'odbcListDrivers' not found
>
> 3: In value[3L] : object 'odbcListDrivers' not found

I am a noob when it comes to this. I have only used R for analyzing local data and never have had to connect to a database. I would very much appreciate if someone could help me solve this!

Comment: From "there is no package called 'bit'" maybe try `install.packages("bit")`?